# Mocha - Selenium webdriver test script throws Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Below is the test code statement to launch the Chrome browser.  Same issue noticed for IE browser too.

```
driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
```

Following error is noticed when running mocha-selenium webdriver script remotely:

> Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH.
>
> Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from
>
> http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
>
> at Error (native)
>
> at new ServiceBuilder (node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js)
>
> at getDefaultService (node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js)
>
> at Builder.build (node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js)

Note that the location to the `Chromedriver.exe` file is already placed in the Path environmental variable under the System variables section. The error above is noticed when the script is executed remotely.  Works fine locally.